# How to pass multiple variables as values in second sqlite execute argument

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I have a database, and I wish to add multiple values to the same row. I am somewhat new with sqlite and databases, but I am learning. I know I can do this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlitedb.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS threadTable(threadName varchar(30)')
c.execute('INSERT INTO threadTable (threadName) Values(?), x.Name')
```

This works for me, but I want to pass **Multiple** variables into the table, like so:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlitedb.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS threadTable(threadName varchar(30),threadKey varchar(10),threadID varchar(1000))')

c.execute('INSERT INTO threadTable (threadName),(threadKey),(threadID) VALUES(?,?,?)', (x.Name, x.Key, x.ID))
```

When I try this, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Files/main.py", line 39, in <module>
    c.execute('INSERT INTO threadTable (threadName),(threadKey),(threadID) VALUES(?,?,?)', (x.Name, x.Key, x.ID))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need parantheses around each column :

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO threadTable (threadName,threadKey,threadID) VALUES(?,?,?)', (x.Name, x.Key, x.ID))
```

Comment: now it says this: ```sqlite3.OperationalError: table threadTable has no column named threadID```

Comment: honeslty i think i want them in the same row. cause I have 3 other thread ID, Keys, and Names to add in seperate rows

Comment: seems like your table dosn't have that column , drop the table and recreate it

Comment: I renamed it to threadsTable, and it worked